# Microsoft Graph API - OneNote - Adding Line Height

Tags: html, microsoft-graph-api, onenote

I can add line height in the OneNote app, but when I download the page's HTML via the API, I don't see any HTML that would indicate the line height is set.

For example - take this page...

[OneNote page - plain text input - no line spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eslmG.png)

The HTML generated is...

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="created" content="2022-02-17T21:57:00.0000000" />
    </head>
    <body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
        <div style="position:absolute;left:48px;top:115px;width:720px">
            <p style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">~~~...ALL THAT TEXT FROM THE IMAGE...~~~</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's how I set the line spacing...

[Setting the line spacing in OneNote for the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jakhK.png)

[And here's the OneNote page with the line spacing applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bda5E.png)

But, as you can see, the HTML retrieved for that page from API doesn't really change.

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="created" content="2022-02-17T21:57:00.0000000" />
    </head>
    <body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
        <div style="position:absolute;left:48px;top:115px;width:720px">
            <p style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">~~~...ALL THAT TEXT...~~~</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

At this point, my guess is the line height (like the page background, etc.) is not stored with the page and not accessible via the API (unless someone knows different). So, I think I'm going to have to try to work with the OneNote supported HTML tags to figure out a different solution.

Again, I'm trying to control line height / spacing. All I could find on allowed tags is in the MS Graph API documentation, but it links out to what appears to be a more complete list, but the link is broken -- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/concepts/onenote-create-page.md

I've tried -

- The line height style, but that seems to have no effect (assuming it's not supported by OneNote)
- I've tried making every space in the content a span with a different font-height and space, but that ends up with some weird formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not export in OneNote, But as per your requirement it seems we can get the below INPUT attribute in OUTPUT attribute on our HTML code.

`data-id`,`data-tag`,`id`,`style`

For example:

Input Attribute:

```
<h1>Heading <i>One</i> text</h1>
<p style="font-size:8pt;color:green;font-family:Courier;text-align:center">Some text</p>
<p>Some <span  style="font-size:16px;color:#ff0000;font-family:Segoe UI Black">more</span> text</p>
```

Output Attribute:

```
<h1 style="font-size:16pt;color:#1e4e79;margin-top:11pt;margin-bottom:11pt">Heading <span style="font-style:italic">One</span> text</h1>
<p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-family:Courier;font-size:8pt;color:green">Some text</span></p>
<p>Some <span style="font-family:Segoe UI Black;font-size:12pt;color:red">more</span> text</p>
```

For more information please refer this ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATIONs***:- [***Input and output HTML in OneNote pages***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-input-output-html#paragraphs-and-headings) & [***Create OneNote pages***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-create-page)

Comment: Yep - I recently discovered this myself and had it on my list to come back and answer this question. I ended up passing <p>s into OneNote - OneNote will automatically add the inner span. OneNote will also peel off any styles on the given <p> that don't apply, but do apply on the inner span, and it will move them there. I used padding/margin on the <p> on to achieve a line-height. Also, if I wanted this line-height to be carried over to 'wrap around' lines, I ended up having to count characters in a mono-space font and create a new line manually when the desired line width was reached.